# thrust::transform() causes cudaErrorIllegalAddress from host to device

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

The following `test.cu` program

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

using HOST_TYPE=int32_t;
using DEVICE_TYPE=int;

template <typename T>
struct Cast {
  __host__ __device__ T operator()(HOST_TYPE i) const {
    return static_cast<T>(i);
  }
};

int main() {
    // Initialize host data
    thrust::host_vector<HOST_TYPE> const h_vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    // Allocate space on the device
    thrust::device_vector<DEVICE_TYPE> device_data(h_vec.size());

    // Copy data from host to device
    //thrust::copy(h_vec.cbegin(), h_vec.cend(), device_data.begin());  // this works
    thrust::transform(h_vec.cbegin(), h_vec.cend(), device_data.begin(), Cast<DEVICE_TYPE>{});
    
    // Copy back to host to check
    thrust::host_vector<DEVICE_TYPE> host_data_copy = device_data;
    for (DEVICE_TYPE val : host_data_copy) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

causes

```
$ nvcc test.cu
$ ./a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  parallel_for: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This occurs at the line

```
thrust::transform(h_vec.cbegin(), h_vec.cend(), device_data.begin(), Cast<DEVICE_TYPE>{});
```

even though a similar `thrust::copy()` runs fine:

```
thrust::copy(h_vec.cbegin(), h_vec.cend(), device_data.begin());  // this works
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the docs to say that `thrust::transform()` shouldn't transform data between device and host. Did I miss this somewhere?

Using `thrust::host` or `thrust::device` execution policies did not help.

Version:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_17:16:49_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.103
Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33492891_0
```

Note: The practical application of this requires `HOST_TYPE=char` but it was changed to `HOST_TYPE=int32_t` for debugging/illustrative purposes, and for comparison with `std::copy()`.

Comment: FYI: You can use a `thrust::universal_vector<HOST_TYPE, thrust::mr::stateless_resource_allocator<HOST_TYPE, thrust::cuda::universal_host_pinned_memory_resource>>`. Pinned memory is accessible from both host and device. The normal `universal_vector` uses managed memory which should also work but might be less portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [Transformations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#transformations):

> With the exception of `thrust::copy`, which can copy data between host and device, all iterator arguments to a Thrust algorithm should live in the same place: either all on the host or all on the device. When this requirement is violated the compiler will produce an error message.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I missed. `When this requirement is violated the compiler will produce an error message.` I wish that were true!

Comment: @Matt, agree. Should be a good reason to issue a defect to NVIDIA.